# I have a string : good morning*12, i want to show like this good morning and remove the numeric value included with "*",

Tags: php

I have a string : `good morning*12`,

i want to show like this good morning and remove the numeric value included with "*",
but my after * the values may be two or one character

like...

```
1> good morning*5

2> good morning*51


1> good morning*5
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

*using `explode()`*

```
$old_string = "good morning*12";
$array = explode("*", $old_string);
$new_string = $array[0];
```

*using `preg_replace()`*

```
$old_string = "good morning*12";
$new_string = preg_replace("/\*.*/", "", $old_string);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Ed Cottrell, You Solve My problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the strpos and substr methods.

Php manual: http://php.net/strrpos and http://www.php.net/substr